# Selenium or browser doesn't utilize enough thread and core to run

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browser

After upgrading my PC from a single 2696v3 CPU to a dual 2696v3 setup with the motherboard changed, I encountered a questionable situation when my code didn't run as fast as before. I run about 15 browser instances in parallel to scrape data from a website and all the cores and threads are utilized when I am using a single CPU.

And now after the upgrade, same code, same environment and even reinstalled Windows just to be sure. I checked the Task Manager and saw it only utilized 8 threads out of my 72 threads dual CPU so it ran very slow. I have tried to stress test the CPU and saw it can go to 100% just fine, this never happened on my old setup. What have I done wrong here? Dont know because of Selenium, IDE (Intellij) or the browser ?
[image]

Comment: Oops! You forgot to post your code

Comment: I just added it in, doesn't think it would help but more information better than less i guess

Comment: Found my answer, I need to use Windows Server for this